# The "(optional)" marker in cppreference.com documentation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Last week, I had a discussion with a colleague in understanding the documentation of C++ features on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/). We had a look at the documentation of the [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), in particular the meaning of the `(optional)` marker:

[image]

(Another example can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).)

I thought it means that this part of the syntax is optional. Meaning I can omit this part in the syntax, but it is always required to be supported by the compiler to comply with the C++ standard. But he stated that it means that it is optional in the standard and that a compiler does not need to support this feature to comply to the standard. Which is it? Both of these explanations make sense to me.

I couldn't find any kind of explanation on the cppreference web site. I also tried to google it but always landed at `std::optional`...

Comment: You're right, and your colleague is talking nonsense.

Comment: It may help to refer to a more familiar example, like the page on [function declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). Unless your colleague thinks that supporting cv-qualifiers is optional, it should clear that (optional) refers to the syntax, not to compiler support. cppreference itself doesn't state any usage guidance on its page for the [optional mark](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:mark_optional).

Comment: Or look at the [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). If your colleague was right, then compilers supporting `int x = 42;` would be optional.

Comment: In some contexts that optional marker does mean the compiler implementation doesn't need it to be compliant. See [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: FWIW, the terminology with which the standard refers to behaviour that may vary by compilers is _"implementation-defined"_ and _"language extension"_

Comment: I didn't expect it to be confusing when I added this marker to [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Maybe I should've avoided using it outside syntax descriptions. :/

Comment: @cpplearner Maybe we could use another marker? Is it _(implementation-defined)_?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The <sub>opt</sub> / <sub>(optional)</sub> suffix means the symbol is optional [for the C++ programmer to use; not the compiler to support]**

As this question has been tagged language-lawyer, and as general when we look for a definite reference, let's move away from CppReference and [into the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861).

Where CppReference uses the <sub>*(optional)*</sub> subscript, the standard uses <sub>*opt*</sub>; e.g. as in [[temp.param]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#1):

> The syntax for template-parameters is:
>
> - template-parameter:
>
>   - type-parameter
>   - parameter-declaration
> - type-parameter:
>
>   - type-parameter-key ...<sub>opt</sub> identifier<sub>opt</sub>
>   - [... and so on]

[[syntax]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/syntax#1) describe the syntax notation [**emphasis** mine]:

> In the syntax notation used in this document, syntactic categories are
> indicated by italic type, and literal words and characters in constant
> width type. Alternatives are listed on separate lines except in a few
> cases where a long set of alternatives is marked by the phrase “one
> of”. If the text of an alternative is too long to fit on a line, the
> text is continued on subsequent lines indented from the first one.
> **An optional terminal or non-terminal symbol is indicated by the subscript “<sub>opt</sub>"**, so
>
> - { expression<sub>opt</sub> }
>
> indicates an optional expression enclosed in braces.

Thus, you are correct, and your colleague is wrong. Particularly for your example of template parameter packs (which we introduce by the optional `...` after `typename`) the `identifier` that follows after `typename...`, which names the pack (or the template parameter, if `...` is omitted), is optional.

---

> But he stated that it means that it is optional in the standard and that a compiler does not need to support this feature to comply to the standard.

The ridiculousness of this claim becomes even more clear if we annotate the "optional permutations" of a class template with a single type template parameter:

```
template<typename>
      // ^^^^^^^^ type-parameter
      // (omitting optional '...' and 'identifier')
struct S;

template<typename T>
      // ^^^^^^^^^^ type-parameter
      // (omitting optional '...')
struct S;

template<typename...>
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^ type-parameter
      // (omitting optional 'identifier')
struct S;

template<typename... Ts>
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type-parameter
struct S;
```

If the claim above was true, only the first of these four would *need* to be supported by a compliant implementation (based solely on grammar, in this contrived example), which would mean a compiler vendor could offer a compliant implementation where we could never name neither template (type) parameters nor function parameters.

Answer (score 15):

It means that particular token is optional. For instance both these declarations work:

```
template <class... Args>
void foo();

template <class...>
void bar();
```

Comment: Optional for _who_, though. The question isn't proposing that optional doesn't mean optional, it's asking whether optional means optional for the C++ programmer (but required for the C++ compiler writer to implement support for), or does it mean that the C++ standard says that it's optional for the compiler implementer to offer support for that syntax.

Comment: @R.M. since I say "the token is optional" I think it's clear we are talking about the language grammar.

Answer (score 5):

While I found a page that lists all of the marks, I was unable to find a page that specifies what the marks are intended to mean. Still, I might ask your colleague to take a look at some other pages, with the goal of the colleague abandoning the idea that "optional" means "optional to support". (This is not a definitive argument, but many would find it persuasive.) I found two good examples at [Function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).

1. [Function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_declaration):
   `noptr-declarator ( parameter-list ) cv(optional) ref(optional) except(optional) attr(optional)`
   Focus on `cv` (short for "const-volatile"), which is marked "optional" and which is "only allowed in non-static member function declarations". Your colleague's interpretation of this marker would mean that compilers do not have to support `const` member functions, as the `const` keyword is "optional".
2. [Function definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition), the first option for `function-body`:
   `ctor-initializer(optional) compound-statement`
   The "optional" part here is the member initializer list (only allowed in constructors). Is your colleague ready to claim that a compiler need not support member initializer lists?

Sometimes one should look at the familiar to understand annotations.

Comment: OK, so after answering I looked at the comments on the question and saw that Brian went down this same train of thought. Didn't mean to tread on someone's toes, but then again Brian could have posted as an answer instead of a comment...