# What does the "(C23)" marker next to "(optional)" mean on cppreference.com?

Tags: c

I once asked [The "(optional)" marker in cppreference.com documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876460/the-optional-marker-in-cppreference-com-documentation).

I found another use of the `(optional)` marker in cppreference documentation:

[image]

As already mentioned in some comments on my last question the `(optional)` means here that it might be supported by the compiler or might not.

But what does the additional `(C23)` marker mean in combination with the `(optional)` marker?

Are those Defines optional for everything before C23 and C23 makes it mandatory? Or is it optional from starting with version C23?

Comment: They are introduced in C23, but optional for the compiler.

Comment: They are optional because the types they correspond to are optional. If any of the types `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t` or `int64_t` are defined, then the `_WIDTH` macro for each of those existing types must be defined (for C23 onwards).

Comment: And they are optional because C can be implemented on systems that might not have, for example, any 16-bit integer type. Perhaps it does have a 24-bit type instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that they may be introduced in the upcoming, yet to be released C standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x, informally called C23. What this standard will contain is so far only proposed.

And if introduced, they will be optional for the compiler to implement. That is, some `__STDC_FEATURE_NAME__` macro will be set to 1 or 0 if the compiler decides to support it or not.

One notable, related example is that the fixed width types `intxx_t` in stdint.h have so far been optional to implement (unlike `intxx_least_t` etc), but it was proposed that they are made mandatory [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2821.htm).